# WAS MQ .net Consumer need WAS MQ Client?

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a WAS MQ server and some queues which have couple of messages. I have a java consumer to get those messages and everything is OK. When I want to get those messages by `.net or delphi` application; it's not working and throw an `error code 2058`. When I install `WAS MQ Client` in my PC; the error went away.

I want to install my .net app in more than 25 clients and I do not want to install `WAS MQ Client` to all of those clients. Is there a .dll or configuration or something like that to avoid install `WAS MQ Client`?

I am using these two dll: `amqmdnet.dll, amqmdxcs.dll`

Comment: here is the question like mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419978/net-using-ibm-mq-without-full-mq-client-install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately It's not possible for now.
See below link for more details:
[.net using IBM MQ without full MQ client install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419978/net-using-ibm-mq-without-full-mq-client-install)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=63371&sid=4bd97b514173cf30abd60a9f7237d51a) is a good document to solve this problem.
I think in .NET we have to using Managed Connections instead of MQ Client.